# Why dismax q.alt doesn't return any result

Tags: solr, dismax

I'm new to solr.
After following the tutorial exercise 1(https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/solr-tutorial.html), I'm able to do some solr query on my loacl machine.

If I want to get result without condition, I will do the query like

`http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/techproducts/query?q=*:*&q.op=OR`

This works pretty fine.

But when I switch to "dismax" and try to have similar result, I do need to use "q.alt".
The query is like

`http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/techproducts/query?q.op=OR&defType=dismax&q.alt=*:*`

However, this query resulted in no result, which is pretty weird.
Even thought I specified the row, it still won't work.

`http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/techproducts/query?q.op=OR&defType=dismax&q.alt=*:*&row=0`

Does anyone face the same problem before?

Answer (score 0):

These parameters are not meant to be used with the user interface URLs; they're for sending directly to Solr. The user interface is a Javascript interface that talks to the Solr API behind the scenes. You can see that your urls have a local anchor in them (`#`), and this is just references that the javascript based user interface uses to load the correct page.

The `rows` parameter is also named `rows`, not `row` - and when used with `0`, no documents will be returned (in the example it's given as an example for using facets with complete counts - you have to ask for facets for that to make sense).

The actual URL to query Solr for matching documents would be:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/techproducts/select?defType=edismax&q.alt=*:*
```

This URL is shown in the user interface over the query results when using the `query` page.

There is also usually no reason to use `dismax` and not `edismax` these days, as `edismax` does everything that the old dismax handler did and with more functionality.